# How can you make a node server running on WSL2 forward over LAN so that it can be accessed by a phone?

Tags: node.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I've tried the following:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCK3easuYm4

https://medium.com/codemonday/access-wsl-localhost-from-lan-for-mobile-testing-8635697f008

https://superuser.com/questions/1679757/how-to-access-windows-localhost-from-wsl2

https://superuser.com/questions/1131874/how-to-access-localhost-of-linux-subsystem-from-windows

https://superuser.com/questions/1732399/cannot-communicate-with-windows-localhost-from-wsl2

https://superuser.com/questions/1594420/cant-access-127-0-0-180-outside-of-wsl2-ubuntu-20-04

https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/11bp9oo/how_do_i_access_live_server_from_phone_i_tried/

https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/m1eb49/cant_access_web_server_from_wsl2_on_my_home/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-a-wsl-2-distribution-from-your-local-area-network-lan

They all share a common procedure:

- Create firewall exceptions for relevant ports
- in Admin PowerShell run:  `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3001 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=3001 connectaddress=(wsl hostname -I)`
- Find windows IPv4 address in PowerShell with `ipconfig`
- on mobile phone, connect to same wifi network
- go to `<windows_IPv4_address>:3001`
- For good measure, in the Node.js Express app, I run:

```js
server.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', ()=> {
    console.log(`⚡️ listening on ${PORT}`);
})
```

What happens:

- Accessing `<windows_IPv4_address>:3001`, `localhost:3001`, `0.0.0.0:3001` and `127.0.0.1` on my phone times out
- Can only view as `localhost` on local computer, not `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1` despite setting `'0.0.0.0'` as a parameter to `server.listen`

So these instructions don't work. I am wondering if the advice is maybe outdated, I am not sure what I'm missing. I wish to access wsl2 localhost from LAN to test on mobile. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd get your phone onto a local network. Most wifi isolate wireless connections. You may need to use the computer's external ip (see https://whatismyipaddress.com/) and set up port forwarding.

Comment: If you run a server from your machine you are able to access it from another machine on the network from it's local ip address. WSL2 makes this difficult because it uses a virtualized environment

Comment: Well, `0.0.0.0` is not a valid IP address of any device. That just means, the process should listen on all available network interfaces, so of course you cannot use it to connect to this device. `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` obviously won't work on the phone either because as `localhost` suggests, these two point to the local device (ie the phone). What seems a bit strange is, that you are able to connect via `localhost` but not `127.0.0.1`. That may have something to do with WSL

Comment: Yeah I was just testing all possibilities. What really should be working is `<windows_IPv4_address>:3001`

Comment: Maybe (Networking considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking). There's a command in there that would bridge your WSL virtual network with your physical network about halfway into the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `localhost` works (from the PC itself) and `127.0.0.1` and the hosts own IP address (eg. `192.168.1.110`) does not - then something basic is wrong, and should be troubleshooted first. Here is a screenshot of a simple python http.server running and listening on `0.0.0.0` inside WSL:

[image: sample IPs]

`0.0.0.0` is a placeholder and basically means "any IP address that the server has". As has been stated in the comments, the WSL is essentially a container inside the computer, which also means that the host computer may have an IP hidden from you which is the one it communicates with the container on.
Setting `0.0.0.0` inside the WSL container does NOT mean that ANY ip address the host PC has will forward traffic to WSL You will need to add something to the configuration, so that the host computer will forward traffic on its external IP to the WSL container.

Just as an example, here is a screenshot of the same windows as above, but the exact same command is run on the host pc:
[image: Host http]

Note that this time the external IP `192.168.1.110` responds with the same response as `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`.

Reading on https://jwstanly.com/blog/article/Port+Forwarding+WSL+2+to+Your+LAN/ you have to do some port forwarding.

*In your WSL2*  execute `ip addr` and copy that (not for `lo`). In my case it was `172.20.204.41`.

*On your host PC* open an administrative powershell window and execute `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3001 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=3001 connectaddress=172.20.204.41`
in that same PS console, execute `netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4` to verify your change.

[image: Working]
[image: working on phone]

If it doesn't work, you have to open the port in your firewall.

In the PS window on the Host execute `New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL2 Port Bridge" -Direction Inbound -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 3001`

This will open the port in your Windows Defender firewall:
[image: firewal screenshot]

*Note* all my screenshots are with port 8000 because I didn't want to spend too much time on this - but all the commands are with the port in your question (3001).